# JTS transform leads to strange results

Tags: java, geotools, jts-topology-suite

I'm trying to transform a JTS geometry from EPSG 3035 to 4326 with the code attached below. However, when I'm just reading the geometry from a WKT, the results are different from the expected value (should be `long: 48°16'17.626", lat: 14°16'55.125"`, according to [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=3035&t_srs=4326&x=4638804.9445011&y=2804557.5654050), but is `POINT (61.90... -19.77...)`).

However, when I switch the coordinate order in the WKT I get the expected results. Is there any way to tell the `WKTReader` or `JTS.transform` to switch up the coordinate order internally?

```java
final WKTReader reader = new WKTReader();
final Geometry geom = reader.read("POINT (4638804.944501147 2804557.565404966)");
final CoordinateReferenceSystem crs3035 = CRS.decode("EPSG:3035");
final CoordinateReferenceSystem crs4326 = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");

final MathTransform metersToDeg = CRS.findMathTransform(crs3035, crs4326);
final Geometry transformed = JTS.transform(geom, metersToDeg);
System.out.println(transformed);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axis order with EPSG:4326 is a nightmare of such complexity that it really needs to be retired by the EPSG and replaced with 2 distinct codes for lat/lon and lon/lat.

For a [quick and dirty fix](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/order.html) you can just try adding `System.setProperty("org.geotools.referencing.forceXY", "true");` to your program. Alternatively, you can use `DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84` instead of decoding an EPSG code which should give you an East/North Axis order (which can always be checked using `CRS.getAxisOrder(crs)`.